# Inserting CDate to SQL Server 2012 Flip Day and Month

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, date, datetime, date-format

I have a problem inserting a date from a VB.net Program to a SqlServer2012 instance.

First here is how i generate the data (Vb.net)

```vb
ExitTime = CDate("1.1.1970 00:00:00").AddSeconds(currentField).ToLocalTime
```

We add this value to a stored procedure (Vb.net)

```vb
With comsql5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExitTime", ExitTime)
```

In the Sql Server stored procedure

```sql
@ExitTime datetime, [...]
[...]
Insert into [table] ([ExitTime]) VALUES (@ExitTime)
```

Here is the output of the exit time in the vb.net
Exit Time : 08/07/2014 2:06:31 PM

Here is the same row in the Sql server database 
2014-08-07 14:06:31.000

What I would like to see in the database is 2014-07-08 14:06:31.00
Because another part in the program does a check on the field but as a String... and it does not match because it flip the month and day

EDIT: TO be clear, I can't change the other part that does the comparison as a string. I know this is a poor way to compare `datetime`.

Thank for your time

Comment: So the datetime value is sql is exactly what you sent it right? The other code that examines a datetime as a string is where the problem lies not in sql server. Keep in mind that what you "see" is not really what is stored in sql server. The best way to compare datetime values is with datetime values, not a string representation.

Comment: I know that what i see is not what is really stored. I will update the question to show the string comparison. Unfortunately I cannot change it this is not my code.

Comment: Change your code in "another part in the program" to not try to compare as a string, but to compare as a datetime value instead, and you won't have any problem. You're trying to work with *presentation* values (what the user sees) instead of *data* values (the way the data is stored), and that's wrong.

Comment: If you can't change code that is written incorrectly there isn't much you can do. You are wanting to change how the sql server engine works because of some rogue code that was written by somebody else (probably a vendor I am guessing). Maybe you can use a computed column to help but that really is dealing with the symptom instead of the problem. I feel your pain, I have been there myself.

Comment: Are you examining the value of ExitTime in the debugger? If so I suspect that it is showing the date in US format, so 08/07/2014 is August 7th and this is exactly what you are seeing in the database.

Comment: The output i provided are from Console.WriteLine(ExitTime).

Comment: I can give you the answer right now. If you want to see date in certain format, you need to set that format. And how date is stored in Sql Server is don't matter. Try this: `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR") dim s as string = DateTime.Now.ToString()`

Comment: if you have a proper datetime variable you can format the output using the tostring method: `somevalidDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")` the problem is that `CDate` largely expects a string formatted in the local culture which is apprarently not what you want.  you will have more trouble getting them back from the DB

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the **Convert** function?

```
SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR, getdate(), 121);
```

Check this links for more information [MSDN - CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187928.aspx) and [SQL Server Datetime Format](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/centurydateformat/)